# Can't switch columns in a 2D array

Tags: c++

How can I switch columns of a 2D array without using functions and so on.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int arr[3][4]= {
 {1,2,3,4},
 {5,6,7,8},
 {6,4,5,3}
 };
 cout << "Before change: "<<endl;
 for (int row=0;row<3;row++){
    for (int col=0;col<4;col++){
        cout << arr[row][col]<<" ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
 }
 cout << "After the row change: "<<endl;
for (int row=2;row>=0;row--){
    for(int col=0;col<4;col++){
        cout<<arr[row][col]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I could switch the rows using a cheap trick I know, but I have a problem with switching the columns. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do mean by switch here? Just print or swap column?

Comment: Yea, i want to swap the 2nd and 4th column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on "want to swap the 2nd and 4th column"

For swapping 2nd and 4th column just add:

```
int temp;
for(int row=0;row<4;row++){
        temp=arr[row][1];
        arr[row][1]=arr[row][3];
        arr[row][3]=temp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Original order

```
int ord [4] = { 0,1,2,3 }
```

Change the ordering

```
swap(ord[1], ord[2]);

cout << "After the row change: "<<endl;
for (int row=2;row>=0;row--){
    for(int col=0;col<4;col++){
        cout<<arr[row][ord[col]]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```